# NSScanner vs. componentsSeparatedByString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsscanner

I have a large text file (about 10 MB). In the text file there are values like (without the empty lines between the rows, I couldn't format it here properly):

```
;string1;stringValue1;

;string2;stringValue2;

;string3;stringValue3;

;string4;stringValue4;
```

I'm parsing all the 'stringX' values to an Array and the 'stringValueX' to another string, using a pretty ugly solution:

```
  words = [rawText componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
  NSEnumerator *word = [words objectEnumerator];

  while(tmpWord = [word nextObject]) {

   if ([tmpWord isEqualToString: @""] || [tmpWord isEqualToString: @"\r\n"] || [tmpWord isEqualToString: @"\n"]) {
    //   NSLog(@"%@*** NOTHING *** ",tmpWord);

   }else { // here I add tmpWord the arrays...
```

I've tried to do this using `NSScanner` by following this example: http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxvi-parsing-csv-data

But I received memory warnings and then it all crashed.

Shall I do this using `NSScanner` and if so, can anyone give me an example of how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: That's a lot things to store in RAM on a mobile device! The code that you omitted would be interesting, too. You can check your memory consumption with Instruments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases `NSScanner` is better suited than `componentsSeparatedByString:`, especially if you are trying to preserve memory.

Your file could be parsed by a loop like this:

```
while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
   NSString *firstPart = @"";
   NSString *secondPart = @"";

   [scanner scanString: @";" intoString: NULL];
   [scanner scanUpToString: @";" intoString: &firstPart];

   [scanner scanString: @";" intoString: NULL];
   [scanner scanUpToString: @";" intoString: &secondPart];

   [scanner scanString: @";" intoString: NULL];

   // TODO: add firstPart and secondPart to your arrays
}
```

You probably need to add error-checking code to this in case you get an invalid file.

Comment: Thanks Sven! I will try this immediately!

Comment: It works great! And it's much nicer than the componentsSeparatedByString: . I think it is a bit slower though, but I think it's more robust.

Comment: Do you just *think* it’s slower or did you *measure* it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use fast enumeration. It's far better than the one using `objectEnumerator`. Try this

```
for (NSString *word in words) {
    // do the thing you need
}
```